# Find arc's mid-point given start, end, and center (of circle) points

Tags: c#, trigonometry

I'm looking for some help on how to find an arc's mid-point. I have the start and end points, center of circle, and radius. I've searched everywhere online and cannot find an answer that I can convert into code anywhere. If anyone has any ideas, please let me know. The following picture is what I'm trying to find (assume that the center of the circle is already found).

[image: Find Midpoint?]

Comment: [This formula](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/RR/database/RR.09.10/akulov2.html) seems simple enough to implement.

Comment: Is it a safe assumption that all values will be positive?

Comment: Yes, all values will be positive.

Comment: As always. What have you come up with this far? What does the circle and circle radius mean??? _A picture please, if I may._

Comment: I just uploaded a picture. Hope it helps. If not, let me know.

Comment: How do you know if given a start and end point if it is the bigger arc or the smaller arc?  (it could go in either direction)

Comment: That's also a question I've been trying to figure out. Would getting the start/end angles help? I have those but I'm reluctant to use them because I use a lot of odd calculations to get the arcs to draw in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

Atan2() of the mean of x1,x2 and the mean of y1,y2 gives you the angle to the mid point. The mid point at the arc is therefore found as:

```
double c=Math.Atan2(y1+y2, x1+x2);
double x_mid=R*Math.Cos(c);
double y_mid=R*Math.Sin(c);
```

Note that I removed the factor of 1/2 (for the mean) from both arguments to Atan2 since that does not change the angle.

**Update:** that this method will always find the mid point on the shortest arc between the two points on the perimeter. That may or may not be what you need.

Comment: Johan, does this give you the midpoint?  I gave me wrong results.  Thanks.

Comment: It claim it does. Can you post example values and how you conclude it's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Take the end points.

```
(x1, y1), (x2, y2)
```

Normalize them about the center of the circle. Then convert to polar.

```
(r, theta1), (r, theta2)
```

The radii will be the same. The center of the arc is

```
(r, (theta2 + theta1) / 2)
```

Convert to Cartesian coordinates and add the coordinates of the center.

EDIT: something like this:

```
def Point CenterOfArc(Point start, end, center)
    let (x1, y1) = (start.x - center.x, start.y - center.y)
    let (x2, y2) = (end.x   - center.x, end.y   - center.y)

    let (r1, theta1) = (sqrt(x1^2 + y1^2), atan(y1/x1))
    let (r2, theta2) = (sqrt(x2^2 + y2^2), atan(y2/x2))
    if (theta1 > theta2) theta2 += 2 * pi

    let (r, theta) = ((r1 + r2) / 2, (theta1 + theta2) / 2) // averaging in case of rounding error

    let (x, y) = (r * cos(theta), r * sin(theta))

    return (x + center.x, y + center.y)
end
```

EDIT2: When you convert to polar, you need to ensure that theta2 > theta1, otherwise it'll be as though the arc was backward.

EDIT3: Also, `tan<sup>-1</sup>(y/x)` is the correct operation, but for many languages, you should call it as `atan2(y, x)` rather than `atan(y/x)`. `atan2` is designed for this use, and it avoids errors when x=0 and may give more accurate results.

Comment: Should be mean of thetha1 and theta2, not difference

Comment: This code works sometimes, but I believe it may be because of the way I am calculating my angles and drawing my arcs. I'm gonna experiment more and when I know for sure that it's my fault, I'll mark this as correct because this should work. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I just tested it without using my angle calculations and it still didn't work. So it's not just my code. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: Originally, depending on which quadrants the start and end points were in, they could be reversed in the result. This should be fixed.

Comment: Are you still getting unexpected answers? Can you give an example?

Comment: @ThomSmith I am having issues with calculating the arc mid point by your formula. The start, end and mid points are {200.4,312.413333333333}
{218.651309974701,374.31673171666}
{166.4,356.08} respectively.

Comment: x2 is never asigned. You should replace :
    `let (` **y1** `, y2) = (end.x   - center.x, end.y   - center.y)`
by :
    `let (` **x2** `, y2) = (end.x   - center.x, end.y   - center.y)`

Answer (score 0):

Although this function returns an approximate point, it's useful for practical purposes.  I just figured this one out myself and it works great.

Prerequisites:
- An arc center of (0, 0) is assumed here, although this could be modified to work with a center point parameter
- You must know the angle at which the arc starts (270 for example)
- You must know the measurement of the angle of the arc (90 degrees for example)

The code below is written in Objective-C:

```
#define   DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees)  ((M_PI * degrees)/ 180)
- (CGPoint)getApproximateMidPointForArcWithStartAngle:(CGFloat)startAngle andDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees {

CGFloat midPointDegrees = fmodf(startAngle + degrees / 2, 360);
CGFloat midStartAngle = midPointDegrees - .1f;
CGFloat midEndAngle = midPointDegrees + .1f;

UIBezierPath *midPointPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(0, 0) radius:self.radius startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(midStartAngle) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(midEndAngle) clockwise:YES];

CGRect midPointPathFrame = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(midPointPath.CGPath);
CGPoint approximateMidPointCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(midPointPathFrame), CGRectGetMidY(midPointPathFrame));
return approximateMidPointCenter;
}
```