# Finding the midpoint in a SVG path

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I currently have a path that is part of a group. I am using Jquery to find the specific path and I would like to find the midpoint of that path. I found this example [on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47258477/how-to-find-the-midpoint-of-arc-in-svg-with-javascript) but when I find my path or the points and try to use `.getTotalLength();` or `.getPointAtLength()`, I get in error in the console that says `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).children(...).getTotalLength is not a function` or `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).children(...)..getPointAtLength() is not a function`.

I read something that those functions are part of `SVGGeometryElement` instead of `SVGPathElement`, but I am not sure exactly what that means or how to use the function now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**path code**

```
<g class="path-line" data-line_id="1"><path stroke-width="5" fill="none" d="M1582.0000915527344,610.0000305175781 C1682.0000915527344,610.0000305175781 1610.0000610351562,710.0000305175781 1711.0000610351562,710.0000305175781" stroke="#000000"></path><rect stroke="none" mask="url(#fc_mask_0_1)" x="1710.0000610351562" y="707.5000305175781" width="21" height="5" fill="#000000"></rect></g>
```

**javascript**

```
    this.objs.lines.on('mouseover', '.line-class', function (e) {
        var len = $(this).children('path').getTotalLength();
        console.log(len);

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `$(this).children('path')[0].getTotalLength();`

```js
$(".path-line").on('mouseover', function (e) {var len = $(this).children('path')[0].getTotalLength();
     console.log(len);
    });
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid; max-width:100vh;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="1580 605 155 110">
  <g class="path-line" data-line_id="1">
  <path stroke-width="5" fill="none" d="M1582.0000915527344,610.0000305175781 C1682.0000915527344,610.0000305175781 1610.0000610351562,710.0000305175781 1711.0000610351562,710.0000305175781" stroke="#000000"></path>
    
    <rect stroke="none"  x="1710.0000610351562" y="707.5000305175781" width="21" height="5" fill="#f00"></rect></g>
  
<circle id="c" r="5" fill="gold" />
<svg>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I know it had to be simple.